# Ansible conditional user based on platform

Tags: ansible

I want to have a different user to be used based on the platform an ansible playbook is run from.

For example I have a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  user: deploy
  tasks:
  - name: hello world
    shell: echo "Hello World"
```

I want that user to be "deploy" when ran on a RedHat, and the environmental variable $USER on a Darwin/Mac system.

How would I set this up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a great question on serverfault that answers this in a few ways: [ansible playbook, different user by operating system](https://serverfault.com/questions/512214/ansible-playbook-different-user-by-operating-system), but it's not a duplicate because it's a different "board".

It's also the top question in the Ansible FAQ, [How do I handle different machines needing different user accounts or ports to log in with?](http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-different-machines-needing-different-user-accounts-or-ports-to-log-in-with), which suggests putting it in the host file with `ansible_ssh_user`.

The ["Ansible best practices" file suggests using `group_vars`](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#operating-system-and-distribution-variance), which is the cleanest option.

For trivial cases, you can also selectively run tasks:

```
- name: run this on debian type systems
  debug msg="hello from debian"
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: ubuntu
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

- name: run this on OSX type systems
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: "{{ lookup('env','USER') }}"
  debug: msg="hello from osx"
  when: ansible_distribution == 'MacOSX'
```

Comment: I found `ansible_os_family` was better to use with `when` since `ansible_os_family == 'Debian'` covers both Ubuntu and Linux Mint for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to know if you are dealing with linux or Mac, you can use the uname output. In a playbook this could look as follows:

```
  - name: check operating system
    shell: uname
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: uname_result
  - name: install tensorflow
    sudo: yes
    shell: pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
    when: uname_result.stdout == 'Linux'
  - name: install tensorflow
    sudo: yes
    shell: pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl
    when: uname_result.stdout == 'Darwin'
```